# "mod_fcgid: process graceful kill" and 500 error each time a large SQL file is uploaded to phpMyAdmin

Tags: linux, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, http-code-500

This is what I'm getting when I tried to upload 19MB SQL file to phpMyAdmin.

[image: Error]

This is part of my `php.ini` most important config:

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 10800
php_value max_input_time         10800
php_value max_execution_time     10800
php_value upload_max_filesize    110M
php_value post_max_size          120M
```

This is my `virtualhost` config:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.77:80>
SuexecUserGroup "#1001" "#1001"
ServerName vuelosenglobos.mx
ServerAlias www.vuelosenglobos.mx
ServerAlias mail.vuelosenglobos.mx
ServerAlias webmail.vuelosenglobos.mx
ServerAlias admin.vuelosenglobos.mx
DocumentRoot /home/vuelosenglobos/public_html
ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/vuelosenglobos.mx_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/vuelosenglobos.mx_access_log combined
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/vuelosenglobos/cgi-bin/
ScriptAlias /awstats/ /home/vuelosenglobos/cgi-bin/
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.php4 index.php5
<Directory /home/vuelosenglobos/public_html>
Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Require all granted
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php7.2
FCGIWrapper /home/vuelosenglobos/fcgi-bin/php7.2.fcgi .php
FCGIWrapper /home/vuelosenglobos/fcgi-bin/php7.2.fcgi .php7.2
</Directory>
<Directory /home/vuelosenglobos/cgi-bin>
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Require all granted
</Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.vuelosenglobos.mx
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://vuelosenglobos.mx:20000/ [R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.vuelosenglobos.mx
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://vuelosenglobos.mx:10000/ [R]
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php7.2
php_admin_value engine Off
FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
<Files awstats.pl>
AuthName "vuelosenglobos.mx statistics"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/vuelosenglobos/.awstats-htpasswd
require valid-user
</Files>
Alias /dav /home/vuelosenglobos/public_html
<Location /dav>
DAV on
AuthType Basic
AuthName "vuelosenglobos.mx"
AuthUserFile /home/vuelosenglobos/etc/dav.digest.passwd
Require valid-user
ForceType text/plain
Satisfy All
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php7.2
RewriteEngine off
</Location>
php_value memory_limit 32M
IPCCommTimeout 41
</VirtualHost>
```

This is my `apache log` which exists into `var/log/apache2/error.log` after upload the 18MB sql file.

```
[Thu Sep 05 19:59:46.372518 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 4295:tid 140548361567168] AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 05 19:59:46.372584 2019] [core:notice] [pid 4295:tid 140548361567168] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 05 19:59:52.065058 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 4295:tid 140548361567168] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Sep 05 19:59:52.148675 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 4703:tid 140382873119680] AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 05 19:59:52.149519 2019] [core:notice] [pid 4703:tid 140382873119680] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 05 20:00:50.877663 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 4703:tid 140382873119680] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Sep 05 20:00:50.978364 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11402] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 05 20:00:50.978441 2019] [core:notice] [pid 11402] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 05 20:00:52.331183 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11402] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Sep 05 20:00:52.405762 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11537] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 05 20:00:52.405811 2019] [core:notice] [pid 11537] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 05 20:02:28.885664 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11537] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Thu Sep 05 20:02:28.963856 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11537] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 05 20:02:28.963889 2019] [core:notice] [pid 11537] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 05 21:03:18.912295 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11537] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Thu Sep 05 21:03:19.006449 2019] [suexec:notice] [pid 11537] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/lib/apache2/suexec)
[Thu Sep 05 21:03:19.006679 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11537] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.1.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 05 21:03:19.006708 2019] [core:notice] [pid 11537] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 05 21:04:22.718938 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11537] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Thu Sep 05 21:04:22.789964 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11537] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.1.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 05 21:04:22.789987 2019] [core:notice] [pid 11537] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 05 21:06:49.756567 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11537] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Thu Sep 05 21:06:49.834302 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11537] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.1.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 05 21:06:49.834330 2019] [core:notice] [pid 11537] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 05 21:10:12.693780 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11537] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Thu Sep 05 21:10:14.929664 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11537] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.1.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 05 21:10:14.929690 2019] [core:notice] [pid 11537] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 05 21:12:08.733759 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11537] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Thu Sep 05 21:12:08.799146 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11537] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.1.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 05 21:12:08.799159 2019] [core:notice] [pid 11537] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 05 21:12:28.027292 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11537] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Thu Sep 05 21:12:28.104604 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11537] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.1.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 05 21:12:28.104640 2019] [core:notice] [pid 11537] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 05 21:13:06.552536 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11537] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Thu Sep 05 21:13:06.689797 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11537] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.1.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 05 21:13:06.689821 2019] [core:notice] [pid 11537] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 05 21:14:37.681439 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11537] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Thu Sep 05 21:14:40.813205 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11537] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.1.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 05 21:14:40.813236 2019] [core:notice] [pid 11537] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 05 21:15:34.605883 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11537] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Thu Sep 05 21:15:34.676336 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11537] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.1.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 05 21:15:34.676353 2019] [core:notice] [pid 11537] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 05 21:20:28.077126 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11537] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Thu Sep 05 21:20:28.214726 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11537] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.1.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 05 21:20:28.214746 2019] [core:notice] [pid 11537] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 05 21:20:30.788218 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11537] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Thu Sep 05 21:20:30.851086 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11537] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.1.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 05 21:20:30.851098 2019] [core:notice] [pid 11537] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mcrypt.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mcrypt.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[Thu Sep 05 21:23:43.791217 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11537] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Sep 05 21:23:45.100510 2019] [suexec:notice] [pid 14875] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/lib/apache2/suexec)
[Thu Sep 05 21:23:45.117855 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 14886] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.1.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 05 21:23:45.117874 2019] [core:notice] [pid 14886] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 05 21:23:57.069123 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 14886] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Sep 05 21:25:31.468868 2019] [suexec:notice] [pid 1933] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/lib/apache2/suexec)
[Thu Sep 05 21:25:36.593240 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2192] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.1.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 05 21:25:36.593277 2019] [core:notice] [pid 2192] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mcrypt.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[Thu Sep 05 21:30:31.912655 2019] [fcgid:warn] [pid 2241] mod_fcgid: process 2444 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mcrypt.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[Thu Sep 05 21:33:27.783041 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2192] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Sep 05 21:33:28.945642 2019] [suexec:notice] [pid 3247] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/lib/apache2/suexec)
[Thu Sep 05 21:33:28.968278 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3249] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.1.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 05 21:33:28.968302 2019] [core:notice] [pid 3249] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 05 21:34:58.135893 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3249] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Sep 05 21:34:59.285509 2019] [suexec:notice] [pid 4146] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/lib/apache2/suexec)
[Thu Sep 05 21:34:59.308968 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4148] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.1.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 05 21:34:59.308988 2019] [core:notice] [pid 4148] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mcrypt.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mcrypt.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[Thu Sep 05 21:37:01.470483 2019] [fcgid:warn] [pid 4152] mod_fcgid: process 4509 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
```

I've restarted apache2 and still not working, i'm recieving the same 500 internal server error. I can see within phpmyadmin import tab that i'm actually avaialble tu upload 110M files.

I'm using `4.9.0.1 phpmyadmin version` and `php7.2` version.

What else can I do?

Comment: That is a lot of log file without much to indicate which lines are logged by this problem.  Do you get the "mod_fcgid: process graceful kill" each time you try to upload the file?   Can you `tail` the log file in a terminal window while you try the upload?

Comment: What about my earlier suggestion of using the command line (`scp` and `mysql`) to import this large file, rather than a web interface that is giving you problems?

Comment: Thanks @StephenOstermiller I'll try to do it trough de command line as you say, and yes, i recieve "mod_fcgid: process graceful kill" warning each time i recieve that 500 error from phpmyadmin interface. Any help?

Comment: After fight against this error i've decided remove phpmyadmin from my webserver and use instead workbench and i also i could import my full sql file. Also, many people told me phpmyadmin is bad, insecure, and have alot of vulnerabilities around.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because you indicate in the comments that you are taking another approach.

Comment: Thanks @StephenOstermiller You closed it?

Comment: I can re-open it if you still need an answer.  I closed it because you said you removed PHP admin.

Comment: Yes, it's ok. Thanks, Stephen.